# How to change visibility of textview on button click without providing ID to them?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, visibility, visible

In this I need to know that how do I access a view without providing the Id to them in this there will be no id provided in any of the file. Without the use of external libraries like viewbinding, databinding, Butterknife etc

Comment: do you want a similar behaviour on anything that you click, is that the reason you don't want to restrict the `id`?

Comment: no only on the child which is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtView;
    ConstraintLayout lay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        lay = ;
//        Log.d("classname", "" + lay);
//        Log.d("childcount", "" + lay.getChildCount());
//
    }

    public void click(View view) {
        Log.d("getparent", "" + view.getParent());
        lay = (ConstraintLayout) view.getParent();
        lay.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        txtView = (TextView) lay.getChildAt(0);
        view.setOnLongClickListener(view1 -> {
            txtView.setText("Hi");
            txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="248dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="click"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a combination of DataBinding, LiveData and ViewModel.

Read more about Data Binding: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

You can enable Data Binding by putting this code in the module's gradle file under android section like this.

```
android {
 buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

In Short

First: You need a LiveData for the values you want to inject in the view and a function to modify it, like this ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _isVisible: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(true)
    val isVisible
        get() = Transformations.map(_isVisible) {
            when (it) {
                true -> View.VISIBLE
                else -> View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }

    fun changeVisibility() {
        _isVisible.value = !_isVisible.value!!
    }
}
```

Second: You need to modify your layout to use our ViewModel by wrapping it in a  element contains  element like this, then simply you can call the variable and functions you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MyFragment">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="MainViewModel"
            type="hazem.projects.testing.ui.main.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some Cool Text"
            android:visibility="@{MainViewModel.isVisible}" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()-> MainViewModel.changeVisibility()}"
            android:text="Change Visibility" />
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Third: You need to modify the fragment to use DataBinding.
this can be done by:

1. replacing the normal layout inflator with our binding object.
2. assign the ViewModel to the binding object
3. assign our fragment as a lifecycleOwner

   ```
    class MainFragment : Fragment() {

        private lateinit var binding: MainFragmentBinding

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {

            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)

            val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

            binding.mainViewModel = viewModel
            binding.lifecycleOwner = this

            return binding.root
        }
   ```

   }

Comment: Ya you are right but the requirement was without databinding, viewbinding and Butterkinfe etc in simple without any lib's

Comment: I think you can get the root view and loop over all its items until you find the textview with the specified text or something. but I think it can be really inefficient.

Comment: ya I found out a way but I don't why a bot is removing my answer